# I can't get get the DT package to work correctly on Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, classification, dt

I'm currently working on an Rshiny webapp to use for some simple classification. Currently, I've been working on creating a table that contains the CCR and MCR of both the CART and LDA methods on the data. My aim is then to highlight the column of the MCR and CCR of the best method (the method with the highest CCR... or lowest MCR). I have ran the code and viewed that it works correctly using the Viewer Pane. However, when I load the app, I obtain the error *'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)*.

Here is my code:

```
data <- read.csv("Fatality-task2.csv")

data$Rate <- as.factor(data$Rate)

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(markdown)
library(gtsummary)
library(ggdendro)
library(factoextra)
library(mclust)
library(cluster)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(DT)
#library(MASS)

glimpse(data)

#################################################################


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("",
             tabPanel("Data Exploration",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput("variable",
                                      "Variable",
                                      colnames(data)),
                          selectInput("rate",
                                      "Rate",
                                      levels(data$Rate))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tableOutput("table"),
                          plotOutput("plot")
                        )
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Classification tools",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput("train.prop",
                                      "Training data proportion",
                                      min = 0.4,
                                      max = 0.8,
                                      step = 0.1,
                                      value = 0.6),
                          radioButtons("prune",
                                       "Pruning option",
                                       choices = c("view pruned tree",
                                                   "view unpruned tree"))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          DTOutput("table2"),
                          plotOutput("plot2")
                          
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)




#################################################################

server <- function(input, output) {

  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    req(input$variable,input$rate)
    data <- data %>%
      filter(Rate == input$rate) %>%
      dplyr::select(input$variable) %>%
      summary() %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      tidyr::separate(Freq, c("Stat", "Value"), sep=":") %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from =Stat, values_from = Value)
    data <- data[, -c(1,2)]
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$variable)
    if (input$variable == "jaild" | input$variable == "Rate"){
      ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, fill = .data[[as.name(input$variable)]])) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.7) +
        if (input$variable == "Rate"){
          theme(legend.position = "none")
        }
    } else {
      ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, y = .data[[as.name(input$variable)]], fill = Rate)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
    }
    
    
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$train.prop,input$prune)
    set.seed(1234)
    n <- nrow(data)
    ind1 <- sample(c(1:n), round(n*as.numeric(input$train.prop)))
    ind2 <- sample(c(1:n)[-ind1], length(c(1:n)[-ind1]))
    
    
    train.data <- data[ind1,]
    valid.data <- data[ind2,]
    
    
    fit.tree <- rpart(Rate~., data = train.data, method = "class")
    
    ptree <- prune(fit.tree, cp = fit.tree$cptable[which.min(fit.tree$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])
    
    if (input$prune == "view pruned tree"){
      rpart.plot(ptree, uniform =TRUE)
    } else {
      rpart.plot(fit.tree)
    }
  })
  
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDT({
    library(MASS)
    set.seed(1234)
    n <- nrow(data)
    ind1 <- sample(c(1:n), round(n*0.6))
    #ind2 <- sample(c(1:n)[-ind1], length(c(1:n)[-ind1]))
    ind2 <- setdiff(c(1:n), ind1)
    
    train.data <- data[ind1,]
    valid.data <- data[ind2,]
    
    #################################
    
    ### fit cart model
    fit.tree <- rpart(Rate~., data = train.data, method = "class")
    
    ### prune the tree
    ptree <- prune(fit.tree, cp = fit.tree$cptable[which.min(fit.tree$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])
    
    ### predict using the validation data on the pruned tree
    pred <- predict(ptree, newdata = valid.data[,-6], type = "class")
    
    ### lda
    
    #lda.model <- lda(train.data[,-6], train.data[,6])
    
    lda.model <- lda(Rate~., data = train.data)
    
    
    lda.pred <- predict(lda.model, newdata = valid.data[,-6])
    
    
    ### create a classification table
    
    length(lda.model)
    
    
    x <- pred == valid.data[,6]
    
    CCR <- length(x[x == TRUE])/nrow(valid.data)
    MCR <- 1 - CCR
    
    CR <- c(CCR, MCR)
    
    z <- lda.pred$class == valid.data[,6]
    
    lda.CCR <- length(z[z == TRUE])/nrow(valid.data)
    lda.MCR <- 1 - lda.CCR
    
    lda.CR <- c(lda.CCR, lda.MCR)
    
    y <- cbind(CR, lda.CR)
    
    y <- as.data.frame(y)
    colnames(y) <- c("CART", "LDA")
    rownames(y) <- c("CCR", "MCR")
    #y
    

    DT::datatable(y, options=list(dom = "t")) %>%
      formatRound(columns = c(1,2), digits = 6) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = colnames(y[which.max(y[1,])]), background = "green")
      

    #colnames(y[1])
    #colnames(y[which.max(y[1,])])
  },
  rownames = TRUE) 
  
}

?formatStyle
?formatRound()

#################################################################
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and here is some of my data:

```
"beertax","jaild","vmiles","unrate","perinc","Rate"
1.53937947750092,"no",7.23388720703125,14.3999996185303,10544.15234375,1
1.78899073600769,"no",7.83634765625,13.6999998092651,10732.7978515625,1
1.71428561210632,"no",8.262990234375,11.1000003814697,11108.791015625,1
1.65254235267639,"no",8.7269169921875,8.89999961853027,11332.626953125,1
1.60990703105927,"no",8.952853515625,9.80000019073486,11661.5068359375,1
1.55999994277954,"no",9.1663017578125,7.80000019073486,11944,1
1.50144362449646,"no",9.6743232421875,7.19999980926514,12368.6240234375,1
0.214797139167786,"yes",6.81015673828125,9.89999961853027,12309.0693359375,1
0.206422030925751,"yes",6.58749462890625,9.10000038146973,12693.8076171875,1
0.296703308820724,"yes",6.70997021484375,5,13265.93359375,1
0.381355941295624,"yes",6.7712626953125,6.5,13726.6953125,1
0.371517032384872,"yes",8.1290078125,6.90000009536743,14107.3271484375,1
0.360000014305115,"yes",9.370654296875,6.19999980926514,14241,1
0.346487015485764,"yes",9.815720703125,6.30000019073486,14408.0849609375,1
0.650358021259308,"no",7.20850048828125,9.80000019073486,10267.302734375,1
0.67545872926712,"no",7.1759169921875,10.1000003814697,10433.486328125,1
0.598901093006134,"no",7.08481982421875,8.89999961853027,10916.4833984375,1
0.577330529689789,"no",7.25391796875,8.69999980926514,11149.3642578125,1
0.562435507774353,"no",7.4689990234375,8.69999980926514,11399.380859375,1
0.545000016689301,"no",7.66583056640625,8.10000038146973,11537,1
0.52454286813736,"no",8.02462548828125,7.69999980926514,11760.3466796875,1
0.107398569583893,"no",6.8586767578125,9.89999961853027,15797.1357421875,0
0.103211015462875,"no",7.21629150390625,9.69999980926514,15970.18359375,0
0.0989011004567146,"no",7.61917578125,7.80000019073486,16590.109375,0
0.0953389853239059,"no",7.87406689453125,7.19999980926514,16985.169921875,0
0.0928792580962181,"no",8.03491015625,6.69999980926514,17356.037109375,0
0.0900000035762787,"no",8.18063330078125,5.80000019073486,17846,0
0.0866217538714409,"no",8.531990234375,5.30000019073486,18049.0859375,0
0.214797139167786,"no",7.742841796875,7.69999980926514,15082.3388671875,1
0.206422030925751,"no",7.65606298828125,6.59999990463257,15131.880859375,1
0.197802200913429,"no",7.7078525390625,5.59999990463257,15486.8134765625,0
0.190677970647812,"no",8.09220947265625,5.90000009536743,15569.9150390625,0
0.185758516192436,"no",8.13137451171875,7.40000009536743,15616.0986328125,0
0.180000007152557,"no",8.18202783203125,7.69999980926514,15605,0
0.173243507742882,"no",8.3807685546875,6.40000009536743,15845.04296875,0
0.224343672394753,"no",6.4400537109375,6.90000009536743,17255.369140625,0
0.233563080430031,"no",6.57004296875,6,17744.265625,0
0.248010993003845,"no",6.68019287109375,4.59999990463257,18760.439453125,0
0.239078402519226,"yes",6.97921484375,4.90000009536743,19312.5,0
```

I know the code works properly - I just want it to be able to run properly on the app. Please help!

Comment: did you just paste your entire Shiny app? Try to make a minimal reproducible example first, that can actually help solve a lot of code problems directly and make it easier for the folks that help

Comment: Your code works fine in RStudio.  Are you getting this error when you deploy in Shiny server?  In that case, you may need to specify where your csv file is located.

Comment: Sorry but what exactly do you mean about the csv file?